# when i run this code it shows Invalid arguments

Tags: python, invalid-argument

```py
File "<ipython-input-7-91f0a9dc7407>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('D:/Berkeley dataset/bdd100k_code/ImageNet/gen_diff.py', wdir='D:/Berkeley dataset/bdd100k_code/ImageNet')

  File "C:\Users\AIRC-GuestR3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\AIRC-GuestR3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "D:/Berkeley dataset/bdd100k_code/ImageNet/gen_diff.py", line 107, in <module>
    '_'+trace[label3]+'.png',x=gen_img_deprocessed,scale=False)

  File "C:\Users\AIRC-GuestR3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 131, in save_img
    scale=scale, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\AIRC-GuestR3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 75, in save_img
    img.save(path, format=file_format, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\AIRC-GuestR3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1991, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: './generated_inputs/light_night_dawn*dusk_daytime.png'
```

Comment: You have an star `*` in your filename

Comment: Where is your code?